# Search function in powerapps for DataTable not working

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-canvas, cds

I have used datatable in powerapps and i used search function using textinputbox.In the search function, when i am trying to set the field name it is showing error.(more info:for the field names i have used relationships such as project.name).

Answer (score 0):

You can search in database using simple queries.

Set Gallery Items property with similar to that formula:
Search(DatabaseName, InputText.Text, ColumnName)